# F10/F11- step into, step over

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

How do <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> work in Asp.net framework.

How do I use them?

Comment: Place your finger on the relevant key, F10 or F11. Then press firmly in a downward motion until it will not depress further. Then release the pressure and remove your finger. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: See here for a treatise on step-over, step-into and step-out-of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/eclipse-debug-step-into-step-over/3580851#3580851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging has got nothing to do with Asp.net but with development environment (in this case Visual Studio). And they are used to step into/over certain line of code. STart debugging by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> in your application.

Comment: i know  iam asking some stupid questions because i am a learner. Please  encourage the learners...don't put them down.

Comment: Robert isn't putting you down.  He's trying to give you some advice about how this community works, and he's got some good points.

Comment: @software: I'm not putting you down at all. No no... Everyone's welcome. I just couldn't say it better than Kyle did.

Comment: The last two paragraphs of your answer should really have been a comment. While you are giving _great_ advice to new members, it really isn't part of the _answer_.

Comment: @Tim Post: Removed additional info since @software went through their questions and accepted answers and did few things as supposed to.