# Where is Step out in eclipse ide debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

When I debug my Java EE application in the Eclipse IDE, I don't see a "Step out" option in the debugger. I only see "Step over", "Step into" and "Step return".

When I have a huge amount of lines I want that the debugger only stops at my breakpoints, so "Step out" is my solution, right?

Comment: I think that step out is exactly the same to step return, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/eclipse-debug-step-into-step-over

Comment: Was it really less work to go on so.com, write 2 paragraphs of text and wait for the answer than just to try all three options?! I mean being lazy is one thing, but stupidly lazy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step return is step out, its also `hotkey F7`

Answer (score 6):

"Step Return" is the command you're looking for. You can press `F7` to invoke it.

From the [Eclipse manual](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-stepreturn.htm):

> Select the Step Return [[image: icon]] command to return from a method which has been stepped into. Even though we return from the method, the remainder of the code inside the method will be executed normally.

Comment: when i have a huge amount of lines i want to the debugger only stop's in my breakpoints so "Step out" it's my solution , right ?

Comment: @Kai: To simply continue execution (till the next breakpoint), click "Resume": http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-resume.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's the little arrow icon that looks like it is originating from two broken blue lines, moving upwards, and then to the right.

You can see it in the Java debugging perspective.