# How debug top-level code only?

Tags: debugging

I'm learning how to use a debugger and wonder if I'm missing the obvious.

My simple script includes two functions that work OK. The main code calls them repeatedly. Is there an easy way to single-step through ONLY the calling code, while the functions and the libraries they use run at normal speed?

I'm using python 2.7 and [pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/), but I'd imagine that people might want this in other debuggers and languages.  Perhaps there's a way to mark sections of code as trusted, and single-step the rest?

Answer (score 0):

With search help from Dani's comment, I found several great explanations elsewhere on Stack Overflow.  My favorite, from [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) on [this Eclipse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/eclipse-debug-step-into-step-over):

> When debugging lines of code, here are the usual scenarios:
>
> - (Step Into) A method is about to be invoked, and you want to debug into the code of that method, so the next step is to go into that method and continue debugging step-by-step.
> - (Step Over) A method is about to be invoked, but you're not interested in debugging this particular invocation, so you want the debugger to execute that method completely as one entire step.
> - (Step Return) You're done debugging this method step-by-step, and you just want the debugger to run the entire method until it returns as one entire step.
> - (Resume) You want the debugger to resume "normal" execution instead of step-by-step.
> - (Line Breakpoint) You don't care how it got there, but if execution reaches a particular line of code, you want the debugger to temporarily pause execution there so you can decide what to do.
>
> Eclipse has other advanced debugging features, but these are the basic
>   fundamentals.