# Sliding Block Solver Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a sliding block solver that has a list of block objects (which contains block size and location of upper left corner), and a 2D array that represents the tray. Wherever there is a block, that location in the array points to the block object, otherwise it is null.

In my solver I'm generating possible moves that haven't been seen, hashing them, then choosing one to do (which changes the tray layout) and calling the solver recursively on the new tray layout. When there are no more possible move layouts that haven't been seen before I return the call, reverse the last move and continue checking the previous call, and so on until either it is solved or I run out of moves (no solution).

The problem is, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception when I make a move. The weird thing is that it only happens after quite a few recursive calls. The program runs through several calls/moves fine, and then it seems to mess up.

generateMoves() tests if a move has been seen before by calling move(), and then reversing the move once it has checked. I think the Null Pointer is happening after it calls move(), and move() is setting toMove = layout[][]. Evidently it is looking up a position in the array that is null instead of one with the block. It seems there is a discrepancy between the list of blocks and the Tray array... Because when move() then calls setTrayAfterMove() it throws the exception. What I can't figure out is why it works for several recursive calls to solveHelper() but then breaks.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class Solver { 
    Tray initial; 
    Tray goal; 
    HashSet<Integer> visited; 
    LinkedList<Integer> movesToSolution; // list of moves leading to solution 
    int recursionCounter; 
    boolean isSolved; 

    public Solver(String initial, String goal) { 
        this.initial = new Tray(initial); 
        this.goal = new Tray(this.initial, goal); 
        visited = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        movesToSolution = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
        recursionCounter = 0; 
        isSolved = false; 
    } 

    public void solve() { 
        if (goal.equals(initial)) { 
            System.out.println("Solver finished no moves"); 
            return; 
        } 
        solveHelper(initial); 
        if (movesToSolution.isEmpty()) { 
            System.out.println("No solution"); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 
        printMoves(); 
        System.out.println("Solver finished"); 
    } 

    private void solveHelper(Tray t) { 
        Stack<Integer> possibleMoves = new Stack<Integer>(); 
        int lastMoveMade = 0; 
        if (recursionCounter > 5000 || isSolved) { 
            return; 
        } 
        if (goal.equals(t)) { 
            isSolved = true; 
            // movesToSolution.addFirst(lastMoveMade); 
            return; 
        } 
        recursionCounter++; 

        LinkedList<Integer> movesToAdd = t.generateMoves(); 
        Iterator<Integer> movesIter = movesToAdd.iterator(); 
        while (movesIter.hasNext()) { 
            possibleMoves.push(movesIter.next()); 
        } 

        while (!possibleMoves.isEmpty()) { 
            lastMoveMade = possibleMoves.pop(); 
            boolean isMoved = t.move(lastMoveMade, false); 

            if (isMoved) { 
                int moveHash = t.hashCode(); 
                visited.add(moveHash); 
                solveHelper(t); 
            } 

            if (isSolved) { 
                movesToSolution.addFirst(lastMoveMade); 
                return; 
            } 
        } 
        t.move(lastMoveMade, true); 
        return; 
    } 

    public void printMoves() { 
        for (Integer move : movesToSolution) { 
            System.out.println(move); 
        } 
    }      

    public class Tray { 
        private int length; // number of rows 
        private int width; // number of columns 
        private LinkedList<Block> blocks; 
        private Block[][] layout; 

        public Tray(String file) { 
            blocks = new LinkedList<Block>(); 
            try { 
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(file)); 
                length = s.nextInt(); 
                width = s.nextInt(); 
                layout = new Block[width][length]; 

                while (s.hasNextLine()) { 
                    int l = s.nextInt(); 
                    int w = s.nextInt(); 
                    int r = s.nextInt(); 
                    int c = s.nextInt(); 
                    Block b = new Block(l, w, r, c); 
                    blocks.add(b); 

                    for (int blockX = b.col; blockX < b.col + b.width; blockX++) { 
                        for (int blockY = b.row; blockY < b.row + b.length; blockY++) { 
                            layout[blockX][blockY] = b; 
                        } 
                    } 
                    s.nextLine(); 
                    // isOK(); 
                } 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                System.out.println("File not found"); 
            } 
        } 

        public Tray(Tray t, String file) { 
            blocks = new LinkedList<Block>(); 
            try { 
                this.length = t.length; 
                this.width = t.width; 
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(file)); 
                layout = new Block[this.width][this.length]; 

                while (s.hasNextLine()) { 
                    int l = s.nextInt(); 
                    int w = s.nextInt(); 
                    int r = s.nextInt(); 
                    int c = s.nextInt(); 
                    Block b = new Block(l, w, r, c); 
                    blocks.add(b); 

                    for (int blockX = b.col; blockX < b.col + b.width; blockX++) { 
                        for (int blockY = b.row; blockY < b.row + b.length; blockY++) { 
                            layout[blockX][blockY] = b; 
                        } 
                    } 
                    s.nextLine(); 
                    // isOK(); 
                } 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                System.out.println("File not found"); 
            } 
        } 

        public void print() { 
            for (Block b : blocks) { 
                System.out.println(b.length + " " + b.width + " " + b.col + " "
                        + b.row); 
            } 
        } 

        public boolean equals(Object o) { 
            for (int x = 0; x < this.width; x++) { 
                for (int y = 0; y < this.length; y++) { 
                    if (this.layout[x][y] != null
                            && (((Tray) o).layout[x][y] == null || !((Tray) o).layout[x][y] 
                                    .equals(this.layout[x][y]))) { 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            return true; 
        } 

        public int hashCode() { 
            // TODO come up with hashcode unique to layout taking in 
            // consideration block at each coordinate, size of block 
            int hashCode = 0; 
            for (Block b : blocks) { 
                hashCode += (17 * (b.width * b.col)) + (7 * (b.length * b.row)); 
            } 
            return hashCode; 
        } 

        public boolean isOK() { 
            Block[][] trayChecker = new Block[width][length]; 
            Iterator<Block> blockIter = blocks.iterator(); 

            while (blockIter.hasNext()) { 
                Block b = blockIter.next(); 
                for (int x = b.col; x < x + b.width; x++) { 
                    for (int y = b.row; y < y + b.length; y++) { 
                        if (trayChecker[x][y] != null) { 
                            throw new IllegalStateException( 
                                    "Two blocks cannot be in the same location"); 
                        } 
                        if (x < 0 || x > width || y < 0 || y > length) { 
                            throw new IllegalStateException( 
                                    "Block must be completely on the board"); 
                        } 
                        trayChecker[x][y] = b; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            return true; 
        } 

        // only returns possible valid moves that haven't been seen before 
        public LinkedList<Integer> generateMoves() { 
            LinkedList<Integer> movesToTry = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
            // TODO: generate moves that haven't been seen 
            int[] moveDir = { -10, 10, -1, 1 }; 
            for (Block b : blocks) { 
                for (int m : moveDir) { 
                    if (canMove(b, m)) { 
                        int trayMove = createMove(b, m); 
                        move(trayMove, false); 
                        if (!visited.contains(hashCode())) { 
                            movesToTry.add(trayMove); 
                        } 
                        move(trayMove, true); // reverse the move 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            return movesToTry; 
        } 

        public boolean canMove(Block b, int dir) { 
            int tmp = Math.abs(dir); 
            int y = tmp % 10; 
            int x = tmp / 10; 
            if (dir < 0) { 
                x = -x; 
                y = -y; 
            } 

            if ((b.col + x < 0 || b.col + b.width + x > this.width) 
                    || (b.row + y < 0 || b.row + b.length + y > this.length)) { 
                return false; 
            } 

            if (x == 0) { 
                for (int xBlock = b.col; xBlock < b.col + b.width; xBlock++) { 
                    if (layout[xBlock][b.row + y] != null) { 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                    // } else if(x > 0 && layout[xBlock][b.row + y + b.length - 
                    // 1] != null) { 
                    // return false; 
                    // } 
                } 
            } 

            if (y == 0) { 
                for (int yBlock = b.row; yBlock < b.row + b.length; yBlock++) { 
                    if (layout[b.col + x][yBlock] != null) { 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                    // } else if(x > 0 && layout[b.col + x + b.width - 
                    // 1][yBlock] != null) { 
                    // return false; 
                    // } 
                } 
            } 

            return true; 
        } 

        // only takes valid input 
        public boolean move(int moveDirections, boolean reverse) { 
            Block toMove = null; 
            if (moveDirections == 0) { 
                return false; 
            } 

            // System.out.println(moveDirections + " " + recursionCounter); 
            int tmp = Math.abs(moveDirections); 
            int moveY = tmp % 10; 
            tmp /= 10; 
            int moveX = tmp % 10; 
            tmp /= 10; 
            int blockY = tmp % 1000; 
            tmp /= 1000; 
            int blockX = tmp; 
            System.out.println(blockX + " + " + blockY); 

            if (reverse) { 
                if (moveDirections > 0) { 
                    toMove = layout[blockX + moveX][blockY + moveY]; 
                } else { 
                    toMove = layout[blockX - moveX][blockY - moveY]; 
                } 
                setTrayAfterMove(toMove, true); 
                if (moveDirections < 0) { 
                    toMove.col += moveX; 
                    toMove.row += moveY; 
                } else { 
                    toMove.col -= moveX; 
                    toMove.row -= moveY; 
                } 

                setTrayAfterMove(toMove, false); 
            } else { 
                toMove = layout[blockX][blockY]; 
                setTrayAfterMove(toMove, true); 
                if (moveDirections < 0) { 
                    toMove.col -= moveX; 
                    toMove.row -= moveY; 
                } else { 
                    toMove.col += moveX; 
                    toMove.row += moveY; 
                } 
                setTrayAfterMove(toMove, false); 
            } 
            return true; 
            // 256x256 
            // 1x256 23x256 
            // 100x01 100x001 100x100 
            // 1x01 1x001 1x100 
            // 10x01 10x001 10x100 
        } 

        private int createMove(Block b, int dir) { 
            // multiply b.x to get 8 digits 
            // multiply bh .y to get 5 digits 
            int move = b.col * 100000; 
            move += (b.row * 100); 
            move += Math.abs(dir); 
            if (dir < 0) { 
                move *= -1; 
            } 
            return move; 
        } 

        private void setTrayAfterMove(Block b, boolean isBeforeMove) { 
            for (int blockX = b.col; blockX < b.col + b.width; blockX++) { 
                for (int blockY = b.row; blockY < b.row + b.length; blockY++) { 
                    if(isBeforeMove) { 
                        layout[blockX][blockY] = null; 
                    } else { 
                        layout[blockX][blockY] = b; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public class Block { 
        private int length; 
        private int width; 
        private int row; 
        private int col; 

        public Block(int l, int w, int r, int c) { 
            length = l; 
            width = w; 
            row = r; 
            col = c; 
        } 

        public boolean equals(Block b) { 
            return this.length == b.length && this.width == b.width 
                    && this.row == b.row && this.col == b.col; 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        if (args.length < 2 || args.length > 3) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( 
                    "Must have at least 2 and no more than 3 arguments"); 
        } 

        String initialLayout = args[0]; 
        String goalLayout = args[1]; 
        String debug = ""; 

        if (args.length == 3) { 
            if (args[0].substring(0, 2).equals("-o")) { 
                debug = args[0].substring(2, args[0].length()); 
                switch (debug) { 
                // cases for debugging arguments go here 
                } 
            } else { 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( 
                        "First argument must start with -o"); 
            } 
            initialLayout = args[1]; 
            goalLayout = args[2]; 
        } 

        Solver s = new Solver(initialLayout, goalLayout); 
        s.solve(); 
    } 
}
```

Could someone please take a look at my code? Suggestions on how to improve efficiency are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if your code were ***here***, not in some link. Also please show which line is causing the NPE to occur for in there lies the secret to the solution -- finding out which variable on that line is null.

Comment: I've edited your post and have added your linked code. That's a h3ll of a lot of code to ask volunteers to go through. Please help limit our work by indicating which line causes the NPE.

Comment: What have you done to track down the problem? What line throws the NPE?

Comment: Edited to provide more detail about what is causing the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/eclipse-debug-step-into-step-over

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solving your problem, let me give you some advice on how you can root cause this yourself.

- Are you developing in and [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)?  If you aren't, start now.
- Have you ever used a debugger?  If not, start now.
- Have you ever set a conditional [breakpoint](http://jetbrains.dzone.com/tips/set-conditional-breakpoints-id)?  If not, start now.

Set a conditional breakpoint on the variable that is null, with the condition being that the variable is null.  Run your program in debug mode and see whats going on.

If the community solves this problem for you, you haven't learned anything about becoming a better programmer.  Make it a point to solve this problem yourself - otherwise you are just postponing the inevitable : becoming a mediocre programmer.

Comment: Thanks...I had been debugging but didn't know about conditional breakpoints.

Comment: The way we usually thank people on SO is with an upvote, or accepting an answer.