# What is difference between trace into (F7) and step over (F8) in Turbo c++?

Tags: c++

[image]

What is main difference between trace into and step over in turbo c++

Comment: Try, and you see the difference.

Comment: Do note that you really shouldn't use TurboC++.  It is over 20 years old now and isn't even C++98 compliant.  There are much newer free options that you can use.

Comment: You wouldn't need to know the difference if you would've used an actual decent compiler.

Comment: The first will move the debugger into the called function, the second will simply execute the function and move on to the next line of the current function.

Comment: I found this on google http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/111-debugging-your-program-stepping-and-breakpoints/ (not the same debugger but explains the concepts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Step Into and Step Over in the Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/what-is-the-difference-between-step-into-and-step-over-in-the-eclipse-debugger)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following program:

```
void main(String[] args){
    myFunc(); //breakpoint here
}

void myFunc() {
    funcTwo();
}

void funcTwo() {
   int x = 2;
}
```

If you select Step Over, the debugger will run `myFunc` and since there is no next line in the main function, it will end. So you will not see this a break at this line `int x = 2;`. After pressing F8 you will not even see a variable x, because it will just be run not debugged. The debugger sticks to the context of your `main` where you are debugging and not go deeper.

By selecting Trace Into, the debugger will try to run `myFunc`, it will see that when running that line, there are other lines of code inside. It will go deeper until it finds a line of instruction that needs to be run. This allows you to debug `myFunc` and `funcTwo` and variable `x` at the same time as your full application.