# Error using DDD debugger c, no source for printf.c

Tags: c, ddd-debugger

I am using DDD for debugging in C. I get the following error:

`DDD: No source`

`[file-location]/printf.c: No such file or directory`

The error occurs at the following line of code:

`printf("i = %d\n", i);`

My guess is that it is not reading the printf command correctly. How do I fix this? I uninstalled then reinstalled but the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly trying to step *into* the `printf` function as part of your debugging session (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/what-is-the-difference-between-step-into-and-step-over-in-the-eclipse-debugger) for a good answer covering the difference between that and step *over*, amongst other things<sup>(a)</sup>).

It's just saying it doesn't have the source code for that function (it's usually part of the C library itself, not something *you* wrote).

You could *possibly* find/install the source code but I suspect it's unnecessary - I think you can safely assume that the C library functions work as advertised, so just step *over* the calls rather than into them.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Based on the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/pdf/ddd.pdf), DDD appears to use `Step` for step-into and `Next` for step-over. It also has `Finish` which appears to be step-out-of and an `Until` I've not seen elsewhere, which steps until you reach a higher address (so executing entire loops in one go without having to step through every iteration).