# How do I skip external files when debugging a Flutter app in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, visual-studio-code

1. I set a breakpoint because I want to investigate what's going on.
2. I step over/into
3. Suddenly it goes off to a different (external) file. It's a swirl of going back and forth to different files forever and after 15 minutes I'm still not in my file and don't know what bug I have.

How can I force the debugger to stay only in my file/or potentially only in my folder?

Question no.2. What's the diff btw step over and step into?
[image]

Comment: if you've gone too deep try `Step Out (Shift F11)`

Regarding your question about step over and into etc, read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/what-is-the-difference-between-step-into-and-step-over-in-the-eclipse-debugger

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code/69144128#69144128

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, if you want to skip over files that you don't want to debug, usually files in your node_modules etc you can add a setting to tell VSCode to skip the files when debugging, so you can make the configuration only debug your code.

You have to add a setting `skipFiles` to you launch configuration, i.e. `launch.json`

Example:

```js
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "**/app/out/vs/**"
            ]
```

You can read more about excluding the files you don't want to debug [here - Skipping uninteresting code (node, chrome)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome)

Comment: Thanks! I'd seen your answer in another post before posting my question but it was not helpful. Can you please show us the full example of launch.json for flutter?  I couldn't make your example to work. It looks like your example may be for javascript...

Comment: You should have posted your whole launch.json then, the question was generic. anyway you can take a look at this file and see how the `skipFiles` object is set for dart projects. I will add the specific lines you might need for your dart project to the answer

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json

Comment: My bad, I thought it was working but it was NOT. Adding your code "skipFiles" is NOT permitted and copying all launch.json from your link doesn't work either.

Comment: The only thing helpful here would be to see all the launch.json file

Comment: Then add it to your question :D. Anyway I don't have any dart project setup with me to check but, one way is to use VSCode's intellisense `CTRL+SPACE` and find all the options you debugger supports, maybe its named differently and you can find one which can skip files .

Comment: Are you saying that "skipFiles" is not an option in your launch configuration?  Intellisense doesn't show it as an option?

Comment: For VSCode, each debugger can have its own configuration setting, it is determined by this setting `"type": "node",` if you install the chrome debugger extension, the type for it will be `"type": "chrome",` node and chrome debuggers have different settings you can add in your launch.json if you are using some sort of dart debugger  lets say `"type": "dart",` it will have its own settings. You can check the extension documentation for all the settings, some maybe common some might be different. for example in node you can have the `program` setting but not chrome https://i.imgur.com/zfEzLOu.png

Comment: `skipFiles` is specific to Node. Dart has settings to control this - see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682276/25124