# How do I skip files when debugging in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

- I set a breakpoint because I want to investigate what's going on.
- I step over/into
- Suddenly it goes off to a different (external) file.

It's just a swirl of going back and forth to different files forever and after 15 minutes I'm still not in my file and don't know what bug I have.

How can I force the debugger to stay only in my file/or potentially only in my folder?

Here is my launch.json but it's not working. It skips e.g. to framework.dart:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "**/app/out/vs/**"
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: What is the path from your workspace to the folders you wish to skip?

Comment: I'm not sure what the path is. But what I want is the debugger stepper to stay only within my my_project/lib folder. Everything else doesn't interests me.

Comment: But you have to enter your path into the `skipFiles` entry for it to work.

Comment: Don't the "*" solve that? so I don't have to know the full path. If it doesn't how I can find out the path of my workspace?

Answer (score 1):

`skipFiles` is for Node JS and doesn't work for Dart.

The default behaviour using Dart/Flutter is to only debug your files, however if you set a breakpoint inside external files you will be prompted to change the settings.

You can easily change the settings while you're debugging by clicking in the status bar:

[image: Dart debug settings]

Or you can edit them in your VS Code user settings:

[image: Dart debug settings]

If you find that things aren't working as you expect, please do file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code with details and a screenshot showing where the debugger is breaking unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter, the correct updated [2023-july] answer is setting up settings.json like so:

```
"dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
"dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": false,
```